# Maximal ideals in commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be a commutative ring with identiy M $\neq$ R be an ideal.

Suppose that M is maximal $\Rightarrow$ $\forall$ r ∈ R\M, there exists x ∈ R
such that $1_r$ − rx ∈ M.

Comment: This is a completely standard result that you will find in any book or set of notes on commutative algebra.

Comment: I didn't find this results my book.

Comment: Which is? And did you look online at all?

Comment: maybe you write proof

Comment: If you're going to try to be a smart alec, then maybe I should downvote on the grounds that your question shows insufficient research, or perhaps even vote to close for lack of context? More bluntly: put some effort in yourself, please! You haven't even told us why you want a proof of this (again, completely standard bookwork) result. Is it homework? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? How have you tried to use the definitions of the objects involved?

Comment: I want this proof for my exam. I know very little English. I didn't find this proof in my own language.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Observe that $\;M\lneq\langle r,\,M\rangle\implies \langle r,\,M\rangle=R(\ni1)\ldots$